# GRUB2 Insert additional kernel modules

Tags: kernel, boot, grub2, kernel-modules

GRUB2 doesn't have the `menu.lst` file.

How do I configure a boot script.

During boot, I hit <kbd>E</kbd> on the kernel image that I want to modify and make my modifications. But I would prefer to make the modifications in `/grub.d/` folder and then run `update-grub` command.

Basically, I am including certain modules at boot time, using `insmod`, there are too many such modules for me to do it every time, and Im unable to edit those different looking scripts GRUB has currently.

I figured that `/etc/grub.d/` contains files like

```
00_header
10_linux
...
```

but they look like scripts that I should be careful when I modify. Is there a easier way, like using `menu.lst` to configure `grub2`

Comment: the boot loader doesn't deal with kernel modules, the init ramfs does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main config file is `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. As it says at the top:

```
DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE

It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
```

As you can see, `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is generated by files from `/etc/grub.d`.
As mentioned in `/etc/grub.d/README`, you can add extra files to `/etc/grub.d` for custom additions to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. I don't know exactly what you want, but for example you could add the `insmod`s you require to a `/etc/grub.d/01_custom_header`, and after regenerating `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` using `grub-mkconfig`, the contents of this file should then appear in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` after `/etc/grub.d/00_header`.

UPDATE: To be clear, the modules that are loaded by `grub.cfg` are GRUB modules, not kernel modules. These modules are loaded so that GRUB has enough functionality to (for example) handle LVM volumes and read filesystems. This isn't a place where you can put kernel modules. This was prompted by  @Stephane's comment. I should have noticed this earlier but didn't.

Comment: That was helpful, thank you. So what I basically do is copy `00_header` as `01_custom_header` and make whatever `insmod` i want to add in that file and run `grub-mkconfig` and finally run `update-grub`. Right?

Comment: @Vigneshwaren Don't copy, just create a new file. If you copy, you will get the same functionality twice -- what effect that has, I don't know. It might cause `grub-mkconfig` to fail.

Comment: @Vigneshwaren No. The files in that subdirectory are concatenated together. Put the new/extra stuff you want in the new file, you don't want anything from `00_header` because then it will just be repeated. You don't want that.

Comment: @Vigneshwaren You just run `update-grub`. The contents of `update-grub` are just `#!/bin/sh
set -e
exec grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"`